# Do apps check if the network is unsecured before sending data over them?

Tags: networking, public-wifi

I went to a coffee shop and this message appeared on the network wifi screen:

[image]

IIUC You can't make a https request with an open network correct?

**More info:**
What I'm interested about is that the operating system was aware of the risks and I didn't check but I think my browser would warn me on a HTTP connection but I'm wondering why I didn't see any many of warning from the apps (most probably were Electron apps that wrap web pages). And so I know that apps are not supposed to worry about concern but it seems in this case, if login credentials are exposed , then I think it should, correct?

Comment: Wifi security like WPA2/3 is different from HTTPS. there is nothing specific or categorical to HTTPS that relies on secure wifi. it is possible that an app might do a check itself, or that the OS is configured somehow to block HTTPS when on unsecured wifi, but HTTPS itself doesn't particularly care.

Comment: I don't believe that your browser would in fact notice. if it did, then its because someone specifically coded it to do that, using an API provided by the OS. if there is no API, or no one wrote that check in, I don't believe any level 7 application would care about the details of a layer 2 connection. if that were to be a norm, then I would expect the OS to be responsible for it, rather than the individual applications.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks and +1

Answer (score 1):

An *open network* in this case means that the traffic may be relatively easily seen by an attacker.

However, network is usually provided as an abstraction: an application usually do not care of individual bits that are send over a wire. A consequence is that the different abstraction levels can provide their own security.

Https is a protocol that provides encryption and ensures to some degree that you connect to the expected server. So you can definitely make an https request on an open network.

Other protocols (SMTP to send email, POP or IMAP to retrieve email, FTP to transfer files) do not include similar encryption. In such cases an attacker watching the network flow can trivially view your data and credentials.

Note that this answer is oversimplifying the whole crypto topic, that deserve a whole [stackexchange community on its own](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Indeed. On the separation of concerns the application is simply supposed to get and make a secure connection from the operating system and not worry about it but this message raised concerns. In the browser world, we were all told to switch to HTTPS to fix this but this seems like a security flaw. If apps can't tell they are on an open network they could be isn't that an issue?

Comment: `If apps can't tell they are on an open network they could be isn't that an issue?` *If* that *were* an issue, the fact that unsecured / open network exists / is possible in WiFi would be the real issue. The "warnings" you think they should have would be what I'd call "oversecurity" -- irritating non-sense that *some people* (I mean like designer / developer / or actually big corporation) posed on to everyone because they *think* they have the right to tell you / govern (even when it's your own business, nothing like WiFi frequency) how you should use everything.

Comment: Btw, perhaps this odd (sorry, no offense) idea you are having with "warning" comes from the fact that there would be a warning on the browser when https sort of failed, and you think that https is *doomed* to fail whenever you are on open wifi?

Comment: Well, I've seen network software thats available to everyone and it shows plenty of data. In normal network routers you can see URL and query. What you say is what I'm asking about and that is should I be concerned or not. As an app developer I don't remember seeing any API's to detect if I'm on open network. But I have seen HTTPS calls fail when not available. I'll add what I mentioned in another comment... What would be the prudent thing for the average user to do? App developer to do? And should Apple be doing anything differently?

Comment: As an app developer you cannot say a lot about network: it can use VPN and be secure or not, and you will not have a clue (understandably, because this may be risk on itself). If as a developer you want security, implement it in the application by enforcing mutual authentication and crypto. As a user you can only trust application. As Apple you can ensure *some* overall consistency, but as the system is somewhat open, this will have its limits.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS protects the contents of the connection, not necessarily the initial negotiation of that connection. You are still leaking *some* information onto the local network in order to get to an otherwise secure server.

Unless you use a browser that supports [DNS Over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) then you may be leaking information such as your intended destination site to the DNS server in the network you are connecting to.

Open networks also allow someone to potentially control the initial stages of HTTPS negotiation and perform a [Man in the Middle](https://infosecwriteups.com/mitm-wifi-attacks-using-open-networks-7c0cc283524c) attack that means the contents of your HTTPS connection are sent via one certificate that the network controller has full control of and then forwarded on to the final destination. A compromised network could potentially be as good as broadcasting all of your personal data in plaintext.

Using a VPN with a previously set up certificate (that avoids letting the open network substitute its own) would protect you from such attacks, and would protect all other traffic at the same time.

Comment: Fully agree that https is not bulletproof. Event with DNS over HTTPS, you have to use ESNI rather than SNI to not leak info about the target side. For a successful Man in the middle, however, attacker must provided a trusted certificate, which may not be such a trivial step to obtain (unless the client browser is misconfigured).

Comment: @Mokubai I checked if my browser supports DOH and it is set to "default". It is Brave browser running chrome internally. I didn't see the options in the brave://settings but did see it in brave://flags and it is set to "default" but there are options for enabled and enabled and fallback etc. Is default enabled? Since this is on IOS that means it's running Safari no matter what. Can this setting be changed then?

Comment: So should I be concerned about this issue? Should I never use unsecured Wifi then? IOW What do you suggest?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts as mentioned in my last paragraph any good VPN service that sets up security ahead of you connecting to an open network would work around most attacks and leaks. As long they pre-share or bundle the certificates or public keys into their app then you can't be MITM-ed, and as long as it is a system wide VPN then you can't leak data. The only data that can leak from that path is the IP address of your VPN service which will be public information anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Apps that need security are expected to do security at their own level regardless of whether your first-hop connection to the Internet (e.g. your current Wi-Fi network) is secure. There's just no way for apps to know that every hop of the the Internet from the app to the server is secure, so an app has to do its own security between the app and the servers it talks to.

However, not all apps do a great job of doing their own security, and Wi-Fi encryption and VPNs can't really do much to fix that. They may reduce certain kinds of privacy/security threats, but they always leave open the chance that someone spying on a different link of the network will be able to see your traffic that your apps failed to properly secure at their own level.

Comment: I see. As an app developer I don't remember seeing any API's to detect if I'm on open network. But I have seen HTTPS calls fail when not available. What would be the prudent thing for the average user to do? And should Apple be doing anything differently?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Apple's doing the right thing by promoting App Transport Security. For the web in general, initiatives from orgs like EFF like LetsEncrypt.org are moving the whole web in the right direction. IETF (Internet standards) work that Apple is closely involved in, like DNS over HTTPS (DoH), DNS over TLS (DoT), TLS 1.3 (and DTLS-related stuff being done as part of QUIC & HTTP/3), and Encrypted Client Hello (ECH, the successor to "Encrypted SNI") are all moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Spaceman @Spiff. Didn't know that. I appreciate the update.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts The prudent thing for the average user to do is to only install and use apps from companies that care about your privacy and security as much as you do. A user can't turn an untrustworthy app trustworthy. A user can't turn an untrustworthy website trustworthy. If your only threat were someone spying on your first-hop network, then you could mitigate that threat with VPN. But the first hop is not the only place where the network can be untrustworthy.